# Does Windows IoT Core run .NET Core Apps?

Tags: .net, raspberry-pi, .net-core, windowsiot

If so, how? I wanted to develop a console application, but it seems I can only start with a UWP application (that has a GUI).

Answer (score 0):

No current plans for it but if you read though this thread you'll see that it worked in RC1 -- so my guess is it won't take too much effort, but resources are not infinite.

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you're using raspberry pi with ARM32 processor, per this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/) it should come out at some time between Q4 2016 and Q1 2017, so don't expect .NET Core app to work perfectly for now.

However, if you want to start a console application without UWP GUI, [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55b357e1-a533-43ad-82a5-a88ac4b01dec) is a nice VS extension that enables to create C++ console app that runs on windows IoT devices, and [here](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2015/09/22/how-to-run-net-core-application-on-pi2-win10-iot-core.aspx) is a tutorial that shows you how.